# ACL configuration in Kafka connect is not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I setup ACL for 3 node Kafka cluster and able to send and receive for a topic through producer console and consumer console. Now I want to configure Kafka connect with ACL. I tried with SASL_PLAINTEXT combinations and in connect.log file it shows the following error. it is not syncing to from source table to topic, please help where I am missing any configuration.

error log

```
[2020-10-14 07:24:35,874] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=oracle-jdbc-source-mtx_domains_acl5-0} Failed to flush, timed out while waiting for producer to flush outstanding 1
messages (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:448)
[2020-10-14 07:24:35,874] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=oracle-jdbc-source-mtx_domains_acl5-0} Failed to commit offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCo
mmitter:116)"
```

My configuration as per the following files. I have mentioned users in jaas.conf file and setting into the environment.

1: zookeeper.properties.

```
authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
zookeeper.set.acl=true
jaasLoginRenew=3600000
```

2: server.properties

```
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://<server_name>:9092
host.name=server_ip
```

3: schema-registry.properties

```
kafkastore.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
kafkastore.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
metadataServerUrls=SASL_PLAINTEXT://<server_ip>:9092
zookeeper.set.acl=true
kafkastore.group.id=schema-registry-3
```

4: connect-avro-distributed.properties

```
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

5: Source connector script

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{    "name":"oracle-jdbc-source-mtx_domains_acl5",    "config":{       "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",       "tasks.max":"1",       "connection.url":"jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ip>:<port>:<dbname>",       "connection.user":"<username>",        "connection.password":"password",     "numeric.mapping":"best_fit",       "table.whitelist":"TABLENAME",       "mode":"timestamp",       "timestamp.column.name":"CREATED_ON",      "topic.prefix":"",       "validate.non.null":"false",       "transforms":"createKey",       "transforms.createKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",       "transforms.createKey.fields":"DOMAIN_CODE", "sasl.mechanism":"PLAIN", "security.protocol":"SASL_PLAINTEXT","producer.sasl.mechanism":"PLAIN", "producer.security.protocol":"SASL_PLAINTEXT","producer.request.timeout.ms":50000,
"producer.retry.backoff.ms":500, "offset.flush.timeout.ms":50000,"producer.buffer.memory":100,
"sasl.jaas.config":"org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"producer\" password=\"producer\";",
"producer.sasl.jaas.config":"org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"producer\" password=\"producer\";", "key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",       "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true","delete.enabled":"true","key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",       "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081",       "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",       "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081"    } }' http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the following properties to your `connect-distributed.properties`:

```
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT

sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="connect" \
  password="connect-secret";

producer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
producer.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
producer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="connect" \
  password="connect-secret";

consumer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
consumer.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
consumer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="connect" \
  password="connect-secret";
```

Source: [Kafka Connect Security docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_plain.html#kconnect-long)

Comment: i tried the same config but it doesn't worked. I am getting timeout exception. Timeout occurred while reading topic metadata. Could you please help here what could be the issue?