# Kafka source connector for postgres - Day0 load

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am looking for a Kafka source connector for Day0 load from Postgres to Kafka.

Came across Debezium postgres connector.

Docker image,

```
debezium/connect:1.4

docker run -it --rm --name postgres-connect -p 8083:8083 -e BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=host1:8080 -e GROUP_ID=test-1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses debezium/connect:1.4
```

How to pass the postgres host details and kafka sasl config?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For SASL config: please see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64355810/7109598

Comment: Postgres host details should be passed via connector config

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander I am new to kafka connect. Can you tell me how to pass the SASL config file and postgress config to the docker container?

Comment: please see some details in the posted answer

Answer (score 2):

**1. SASL configuration**

1.1. In common case you need to add the following properties to your `connect-distributed.properties`:

```
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT

sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="connect" \
  password="connect-secret";

producer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
producer.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
producer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="connect" \
  password="connect-secret";

consumer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
consumer.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
consumer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="connect" \
  password="connect-secret";
```

*Source*: StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64355810/7109598) "ACL configuration in Kafka connect is not working"

*Reference*: [Kafka Connect Security docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_plain.html#kconnect-long)

1.2. For `debezium/connect` docker image you can try to pass SASL config directly via environment variables (using [these](https://github.com/debezium/docker-images/tree/master/connect-base/1.4#others) transformation steps):

```sh
docker run -it --rm --name postgres-connect -p 8083:8083 \
  -e BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=host1:8080 -e GROUP_ID=test-1 \
  -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs \
  -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets \
  -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses \
  -e CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN \
  -e CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_PLAINTEXT \
  -e CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="connect" password="connect-secret"; \
  -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN \
  -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_PLAINTEXT \
  -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="connect" password="connect-secret"; \
  -e CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN \
  -e CONNECT_CONSUMER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_PLAINTEXT \
  -e CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="connect" password="connect-secret"; \
debezium/connect:1.4
```

**2. PostgreSQL host configaration**

Host details should be passed via Kafka Connect [REST API](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/restapi.html) using connector config:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    http://localhost:8083/connectors/debezium_postgres_source/config \
    -d '{
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "source-db",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "postgresusersource",
    "database.password": "postgrespw",
    "database.dbname" : "sourcedb",
    "database.server.name": "dbserver1"
}'
```

Comment: Calling REST API for Postgres config --> Do we need to call this whenever the docker container gets restarted for some reason?

Comment: All metadata of connector stores in Kafka. So, if you haven't lose this info, I don't have to call this method again. Also you can check status of connector via REST API (curl -XGET http://localhost:8083/connectors/debezium_postgres_source/status)